# Problema aplicando ventana de Hanning a fourier

Tags: python, numpy, ventana

tengo el siguiente código:

```
def Fourier (variable):
    FT = np.zeros(variable.shape)*np.nan
    Frec = np.zeros(variable.shape)*np.nan
    Pot = np.zeros(variable.shape)*np.nan
    Period = np.zeros(variable.shape)*np.nan
    Var=np.zeros(shape=(1,variable.shape[1],variable.shape[2]))*np.nan
    Shape = variable.shape

    for lat in range(Shape[1]):
        for lon in range(Shape[2]):
            pixel = variable[:,lat,lon]
            FT_pixel = np.fft.fft(pixel-np.mean(pixel)) #*np.hanning(len(pixel))
            Frec_pixel = np.fft.fftfreq(len(pixel))
            Pot_pixel = np.abs(FT_pixel*1./len(pixel))**2
            Period_pixel =1./Frec_pixel

            index_pos = np.where(Period_pixel>0)[0]
            
            var1=np.sum(Pot_pixel)
            var2=np.var(pixel)
            #print(var1,var2)

            FT[:,lat,lon] = FT_pixel
            Frec[:,lat,lon] = Frec_pixel
            Pot[:,lat,lon] = Pot_pixel
            Period[:,lat,lon] = Period_pixel
            Var[:,lat,lon]=var1
    return Period,Pot,index_pos,Var,FT_pixel
```

Cuando lo aplico a mi serie de datos, se ven al final unos problemas de borde, por tanto, multiplique el FT por una ventana de hanning, y al graficar el espectro de potencias obtengo un resultado raro, no se que estoy haciendo mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]